# PL/SQL procedures same row

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

Table before solve:

```
       ID NAME             DATA
```

---

```
     1 zhang               9
     1 zhang              12
     2 wang                1
     2 wang                2
```

/*this is the table before solved*/

Table after solve:

```
    ID NAME             DATA
```

---

```
     1 DIY                13
     2 DIY                 3
```

/*this is what I want to get result*/
There is the procedure:

```
update A a 
set a.date=(select  max(f_get(f.id,f.date,g.date))
           from A f,A g 
            where f.date!=g.date 
            and f.id=a.id);


--function f_get()
create or replace function f_get
      (id in varchar2,date in varchar,date2 in varchar ) 
    return varchar is
  Result varchar     
      date3 varchar(4);

begin

      select nvl(date,date2) into date3 
      from dual;

      Result:=date3;

    delete  from A a 
    where a.ID=id  
    and a.date=date2;--there is error 

  return(Result);
end  f_get;
```

Comment: Um, what's the question?

Comment: just  want to  sort this, I  try my best,why  laugh a me ？

Comment: Robot1987, there's nothing in what you've posted that's a question or what you're trying to do that's not working.

Comment: now  there is  a table named A ,it has ID, NAME and DATE,  I just want to write procedur to solve the problem.  my code is error.SO HELP ME TO correct it.  YES,@eaolson

Comment: So you're trying to remove cases where ID and NAME are duplicated? How do you choose between the duplicates? That's an odd date field. I thought it was a binary number when I looked at it. But most importantly: what is the error message you're getting?

Comment: @eaolson there is no error message， Can I use ‘delete’ in a function?  such as 'delete from A a where a.id=id and a.date=date2'     I find  I can not  get  what I want get  using this  procedure.   I want to  get 'ID name date<br>
1 zhang 1101<br>
2 wang 1100 <br>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does its best to hide itself, but this is the point:

> "--there is error "

The error you get is (presumably) `ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query`, which you are getting because you are calling a FUNCTION which includes a DELETE command from a SELECT statement.

Oracle's transactional model doesn't allow queries to change the state of the database.  Instead of a FUNCTION you need to write a procedure.

Although, if you want to remove duplicate rows, a straight SQL solution will suffice.  Something like

```
delete from a
where (id, date) not in 
    ( select id, max(date) from a
      group by id)
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should pay attention how to write questions. It would help us to help you. This is my guess what you are looking for. Unfortunately I don't have 9i available, but hope this helps !

```
create table so7t (
  id number,
  name varchar2(10),
  data number -- date is a reserved word and can't be used as identifier
);

-- 1001
insert into so7t values (1, 'zhang', 9);
-- 1100
insert into so7t values (1, 'zhang', 12);
-- 0001
insert into so7t values (2, 'wang', 1);
-- 0010
insert into so7t values (2, 'wang', 2);

select * from so7t;

/* from http://www.dbsnaps.com/oracle/bitwise-operators-in-oracle/ */
create or replace function bitor (x number, y number)
return number
is
begin
  return (x+y)-bitand(x,y);
end;
/
show errors

create or replace procedure solve (
  p_id in number
) as
  type ids_t is table of number;
  v_ids ids_t;
  v_result number := 0;
begin
  select data bulk collect into v_ids from so7t where id = p_id;

  for i in v_ids.first .. v_ids.last loop
    v_result := bitor(v_result, v_ids(i));
  end loop;

  delete from so7t where id = p_id;

  insert into so7t values (p_id, 'DIY', v_result);
end;
/

begin
  solve(1);
  commit;

  solve(2);
  commit;
end;
/
```

Table before `solve`:

```
        ID NAME             DATA
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 zhang               9
         1 zhang              12
         2 wang                1
         2 wang                2
```

Table after `solve`:

```
        ID NAME             DATA
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 DIY                13
         2 DIY                 3
```

Comment: yes,thankyou verymuch  I will  to learn how to ask a question.  But if  the  ID  is not  ONLY  '1','2'   what can I do? It will be '3' or '212'. "select max(f_get(f.id,f.date,g.date))from A f,A g where f.date!=g.date and f.id=a.id"  what do you think about this, It will be work?

Comment: http://topic.csdn.net/u/20110812/10/6213020a-55a2-4697-a44a-f7f14dcbd853.html?63542      this  is I   write in the BBS.

Comment: @Robot1987 It can be concluded from your question that all types in your table are strings, but you're still explicitly using number values. Don't try to save number information into a string type but instead use a number type. The ID can be any number. In the example I have just picked simple numbers. I'm afraid this is all I can contribute as I'm still very much confused what you're looking for.

Comment: date  varchar2(31)   It will be '1111111111111111111111111111110'  or '1111111111111111111111111000000'  I want to get'1111111111111111111111111111110'.  they are strings. We get the data from other system.I cannot change this. we have to pick the same in the line but not in the  date varcahr2(31). Do you know  what I  am saying?  sorry  English is POOR

Comment: @Robot1987 That is exactly the information you should have implicitly expressed in your question. Please update the exact `create table` statement to your question and learn how to format code. SO has very good help. I have to run now, but I might (or might not) to come back to this issue later.